# TestMethod in Coded UI Test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am creating a TestMethod in Coded UI Test that will access UI Control in my Windows Phone 8.1 apps. I used the async method to perform multi-thread tasking but I got the exception for my code like this:

```
     [TestMethod]
            async public Task CodedUITestMethod1()
            {
                XamlWindow.Launch("{556EE9D4-5640-4120-9916-44B1CA27352F}:App:556ee9d4-5640-4120-9916-44b1ca27352f_tpza89sffjg1j!App");             
                await ExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
                {
                    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
                    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Input.Point point = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Input.Point(mainPage.getX(), mainPage.getY());
                    Gesture.Tap(point);
                }
                    );
}
```

and

```
 public static IAsyncAction ExecuteOnUIThread(Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler action)
        {
            return Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
        }
```

but I got the exception message is: Test Name:  CodedUITestMethod1
Test FullName:  CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
Test Source:    c:\Users\Thanh\Desktop\Calculator\CodedUITestProject2\CodedUITest1.cs : line 28
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:02.3440269

Result Message: 
Test method CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: A method was called at an unexpected time.

A method was called at an unexpected time.
Result StackTrace:
at Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.get_MainView()
   at CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest1.ExecuteOnUIThread(DispatchedHandler action)
   at CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest1.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

So how can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI tests are intended to be called by the Coded UI test control mechanisms within Visual Studio or the associated programs such as `mstest.exe`. All the Coded UI tests I have seen have code such as:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1() { ... }
```

They may also have a `[DataSource(...)]` attribute. The method you tried has a very different type:

```
[TestMethod] async public Task CodedUITestMethod1() { ... }
```

I have not seen any documentation or examples suggesting that such a method can be used with Coded UI.

Having the call of `XamlWindow.Launch(...)` within the `[TestMethod]` suggests you are trying to build the Coded UI tests and application together into one program and then get the test to invoke the application by calling a method within that program. That is not how Coded UI is intended to be used. A Coded UI test suite should be created as separate program (actually a DLL that is called by Visual Studio, by `mstest.exe` or by similar) from the application being tested. Coded UI then runs the application as a program (not by calling a method within the application). The Coded UI test then interacts with the program by reading the screen and by sending keyboard input and mouse clicks to the program.